# both variables decrease proportionately

Tags: javascript, math

Given:

```
x = 0.5;
y = 0.3;

if (x < 0.5) {
   //decrease y to 0 where x reaches 0 at the same time y reaches 0.
}
```

How do I decrease both variables proportionately? So that x and y reach 0 at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My assumption is that you wish to decrease in steps, until eventually both variables reach zero at the same time.*

You can calculate a ratio by which to decrease both variables, based on the size of the step you wish to make.  If you wish to reduce both by 10%, the step size would be 0.1 * x and 0.1 * y.

Note that you should calculate the step size when you first start and retain it.  If you recalculate the step size for every iteration, each step will become smaller and smaller and you would [never quite reach zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise).

Keep in mind that due to floating point inaccuracies you may not ever exactly reach zero.  Depending on your needs, you might test for <= 0.